# Forward a recruiters e-mail vs sending friends' contact details to recruiter

Tags: job-search, recruitment

I got contacted by a recruiter regarding a job opening. I am not interested in the job, but I have some friends that might be.
What would be the best way to connect them?

- A) Give their names to the recruiter.
- B) Forward the recruiter's e-mail to my friends, let them contact the recruiter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What would be the best way to connect them?

Most folks I know **do not** want their personal information (*email, phone, etc.*) shared **without their consent**.

Your best bet is to *just forward the email on to whomever* you think would be interested and let them make contact with the recruiter should they desire to know more about the opportunity.

Comment: as once a recruiter has your info you will never be free.

Comment: +1, it has to be option B.

Answer (score 5):

My initial reaction was: the answer is so obvious, why did you even have to ask? And the other three answers seem to agree. But on reflection, there is a better solution: forward the e-mail to your friends, and *ask* them if they would like you to recommend them to the recruiter.

This way, you are not giving anybody their personal details without their consent, but you offer them the service of giving them a free recommendation, which is surely better than having them contact the recruiter out of the blue.

Comment: Indeed, by doing this, you respect the friends' privacy while still giving them the option to leverage the existing human contact if they so wish.

Comment: What leads you to think this would be out of the blue?  The friend can simply say 'OP forwarded your email to me because they thought I might be interested in this listing...'

Comment: Plus, most recruiters will pay you a few $100 for a recommendation, if they get the job

Answer (score 2):

**Just Forward The Email**

If you forward the recruiter's email to your friends, you're giving your friends an opportunity for this specific job opening.

If you forward your friends' contact info to the recruiter, you're not *just* connecting them with this opportunity.  You're giving that recruiter the ability to bug them... non-stop... for years.  Because that recruiter isn't going to try to connect them to *this one specific* job opening - they're going to try to connect them with *any* job openings that come up.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best way to connect them?
>
> A) Give their names to the recruiter.
>
> B) Forward the recruiter's
>   e-mail to my friends, let them contact the recruiter.

B is by far the best option.

Unless you have your friends' permission to give away their contact information, you should never do that.

If you forward the recruiter's information, along with a brief note, your friends can choose to follow up or to just ignore it, without fear of being hounded by a recruiter.